# VECM model with one I(0) and seven I(1) variables. How to implement it?

Tags: time-series, vector-error-correction-model

I have data with one I(0) and seven I(1) variables. I found by Johansen procedure that maximum cointegration rank is 1 (applied to I(1) variables).
Now I try to understand, how can i add I(0) variable into VECM?